# calling a defined array in Struct to another func in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

i had defined a struct

```
struct  posts {
                var listArray = Dictionary<String, Any>()
}

var categoryId: String?
```

in listArray: "String" will be categoryId values, and "Any" will be an other array which getting its Details from a JSON URL

```
func data(){
    let dataCaching = [posts().listArray[categoryId!]] // here iam getting an error "Missing Argument For parameter 'listArray' in call, what is the right code here?
    if dataCaching == nil {
       <-here some code to url session and jeson url->
    }else{
        println("Data is already cashed")
}
    posts.listArray[categoryId] = json["details"] // what is the right code here too?

}
```

i wonder how to call my listArray From its Struct to Another Function, and how the code will be?

if any thing doesn't decleared, kindly you can ask me,
thanks

Comment: Please be more clear about what you are trying to achieve.  Your question text mentions structs, json, http fetch, caching and arrays, and I can't work out which, of any, you are confused about.  Please pick only one.

Comment: I also suggest you read the documentation for swift until you understand why Cache cannot be nil.

Comment: i only want to know what is the right code to calling my array from its struct to the Func, here is my question

Comment: i made a mistake when defining the variable as Cashe, i changed it to dataCaching

Comment: You did fail to construct an instance of posts correctly.

Comment: in the two situation of this line there is an error ("Missing Argument For parameter 'listArray' in call)

Comment: Because you didn't supply a listArray parameter to the post constructor.  I suspect you don't want to, but there are multiple problems with your code and fixing your code will not make an instructive example for others that is better than reading the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are declaring categoryId as an optional, you need to force unwrap it using the exclamation symbol.

```
func data() {
    let Cache = [posts().listArray[categoryId!]]
    //rest of the code
}

//EDIT:
struct posts {
    var listArray = Dictionary<String,Any>()
    init() {
        //Initalise the dictionary object here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for replying but i am getting an error "Missing Argument For parameter 'listArray' in call, why?

Comment: The default struct constructor takes a parameter for each property in the struct.  Either supply it or build a new constructor.